# How to compare generic parameter types?

Tags: c#, generics, type-parameter

I have a class containing a generic Type:

```
class MyClass<T>
{
}
```

The T type can be any type, including `MyClass<AnotherType>`.
Yes, that's kinda recursive, can have things like `MyClass<MyClass<MyClass<T>>>`.

At some point, inside MyClass, I want to know if `T` is `MyClass<AnyOtherType>` or any type derived from `MyClass<AnyOtherType>`. (Doesn't matter what AnyOtherType is, just need to know if T is MyClass).

So, how do I compare T type with `MyClass<anything>`?

---

Another thing I figured out, to avoid problems with the paramter, is to make `MyClass<T>` inherit `MyClass` (with no parameters), to make the comparison easier.

```
class MyClass<T> : MyClass
```

But still the question remains:

```
How can I compare T with MyClass to know if it's some type that inherits MyClass??
```

Comment: Regarding "the question that remains". `typeof(MyClass).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T))` (I think).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to check with reflection - recursively to account for "derived from":

```
static bool IsMyClass(object obj)
{
    return obj == null ? false : IsMyClass(obj.GetType());
}
static bool IsMyClass(Type type)
{
    while (type != null)
    {
        if (type.IsGenericType &&
            type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(MyClass<>))
        {
            return true;
        }
        type = type.BaseType;
    }
    return false;
}
```