# Check if FieldInfo type is generic class without type

Tags: c#, .net, class, types, field

I've got a generic class (`ClassName<T>`) and I've got several `FieldInfo`s for fields with different `T`s (`Class<bool>`, `Class<int>`, etc...). How do I check if the `FieldInfo`'s type just is `ClassName`, not `ClassName<bool>` or `ClassName<int>`? Here's my code:

```
public class Field<T>
{
    public T value;
    public Field(T value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }
}

...

public class Action_SetPosition : Action
{
    public Field<GameObject> gameObject = new Field<GameObject>(null);
    public Field<Vector3> position = new Field<Vector3>(Vector3.zero);
}

...

FieldInfo[] fields = typeof(Action_SetPosition).GetFields();
for (int a = 0; a < fields.Length; a++)
{
    if (fields[a].FieldType == typeof(Field<ANYTHING>))
    {
    }
}
```

I want to check it the type of `fields[a]` has `Field` in it, and **ANY** `<T>`. Thanks. :)

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15925099/how-to-compare-generic-parameter-types

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to check it the type of fields[a] has Field in it, and ANY . Thanks. :)

I'm not quite sure I understand this statement but I think you are looking for something like this:

```
if(fields[a].IsGenericType && 
   fields[a].FieldType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Field<>))
```

This will return `true` if the field type is `Field<T>` regardless of the type of `T`...

Answer (score 1):

### One way would be with reflection.

But it's kind of ugly and imperformant if you do not cache.

### An easier way is with an interface

You could try this

```
public interface IField {}

public class Field<T> : IField
{
    public T value;
    public Field(T value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }
}

// ...


FieldInfo[] fields = typeof(Action_SetPosition).GetFields();
for (int a = 0; a < fields.Length; a++)
{
    if (fields[a] is IField)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```